# Change Page Size When at Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap for my use....My Question is How to Change the Page size that i declared in my script. To avoid unusual space while pagination.
[HERE AN IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSJn7.png)

1. When Col-xl-3, My page size will be 12
2. And When Col-lg-4, My page size will be 9
3. And When Col-md-6, My page size will be 8

(Changing How much Page content to be Display While Responsive)

```js
pageSize = 8;
pagesCount = $(".content").length;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize);

$('.pagination').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: totalPages,
  visiblePages: 3,
  onPageClick: function(event, page) {
    var startIndex = (pageSize * (page - 1));
    var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
    $('.content').hide().filter(function() {
      var idx = $(this).index();
      return idx >= startIndex && idx < endIndex;
    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="content col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mt-4">
    <div class="content-head">
      <img src="image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content-title">
      <h3 class="text-center">CARD TITLE</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Script and Html Specific Code Block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you must detect your window size:

```
var detect = function(width) {
if (width < 576) {
    callPagination(12);
} else if (width >= 576 && width < 768) {
    callPagination(10);
} else if (width >= 768 && width < 992) {
    callPagination(9);
} else if (width >= 992) {
    callPagination(8);
}};
```

and you must create function:

```
var callPagination = function(pageSize) {
pageSize = pageSize;
pagesCount = $('.content').length;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize);

$('.pagination').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: totalPages,
    visiblePages: 3,
    onPageClick: function(event, page) {
        var startIndex = pageSize * (page - 1);
        var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
        $('.content')
            .hide()
            .filter(function() {
                var idx = $(this).index();
                return idx >= startIndex && idx < endIndex;
            })
            .show();
    }
});};
```

and call function when page is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = window.innerWidth;
detect(width)

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    detect(width)
});});
```